# Three JS objects rotation point

Tags: three.js, rotation, pivot

I'm new in Three JS, learning by myself. I'm creating a spinning fidget spinner, but have one problem. Spinner spinning wrong. I need that all objects will spin round in center point of spinner. Now it making a big round.

I know you don't have time for this stuff, but it will be a good kick to me to keep going.

So my code is:

```
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    var plane;
    loader.load( 'img/stalas.jpg',
        function ( texture ){    // užkrovus
            texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;
            texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;

            var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/stalas.jpg" );

            var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(40,40);
            var planeMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, bumpMap: bump, bumpScale: -0.2, overdraw: 0.5 });

            planeMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

            plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
            plane.receiveShadow = true;
            plane.material.map.repeat.set(1, 1);
            plane.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            plane.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

            plane.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
            plane.position.x=0;
            plane.position.y=0;
            plane.position.z=-5;
            scene.add(plane);
        },
        function ( xhr ) { // krovimo metu
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) { // klaidos atveju
            console.log( 'Texture stalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );

//var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
pivot.position.x=0;
pivot.position.y=3;
pivot.position.z=0;



var torus;
loader.load('img/metalas.jpg',
    function (texture){
        var torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 2, 0.6, 6, 100, 6.3 );
        var torusMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/metalas.jpg" );
        torusMaterial.bumpMap = bump;
        torusMaterial.bumpScale = 0.6;
        torusMaterial.metalness = 0.1; // non metal 0-1 metal default 0.5
        torusMaterial.roughness = 0.8; // mirror 0-1 diffuse default 0.5
        torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
        torus.castShadow = true;
        torus.material.map.repeat.set(0.5,0.5);
        torus.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        torus.position.x=4.5;
        torus.position.y=-2.48;
        torus.position.z=0.5;
pivot.add( torus );
        },
        function (xhr) {
             console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'Texture metalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );
scene.add(pivot);

var torus;
loader.load('img/metalas.jpg',
    function (texture){
        var torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 2, 0.6, 6, 100, 6.3 );
        var torusMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/metalas.jpg" );
        torusMaterial.bumpMap = bump;
        torusMaterial.bumpScale = 0.6;
        torusMaterial.metalness = 0.1; // non metal 0-1 metal default 0.5
        torusMaterial.roughness = 0.8; // mirror 0-1 diffuse default 0.5
        torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
        torus.castShadow = true;
        torus.material.map.repeat.set(0.5,0.5);
        torus.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        torus.position.x=-3;
        torus.position.y=-2.48;
        torus.position.z=5;
pivot.add( torus );
        },
        function (xhr) {
             console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'Texture metalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );
scene.add(pivot);

var torus;
loader.load('img/metalas.jpg',
    function (texture){
        var torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 2, 0.6, 6, 100, 6.3 );
        var torusMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/metalas.jpg" );
        torusMaterial.bumpMap = bump;
        torusMaterial.bumpScale = 0.6;
        torusMaterial.metalness = 0.1; // non metal 0-1 metal default 0.5
        torusMaterial.roughness = 0.8; // mirror 0-1 diffuse default 0.5
        torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
        torus.castShadow = true;
        torus.material.map.repeat.set(0.5,0.5);
        torus.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        torus.position.x=5;
        torus.position.y=-2.48;
        torus.position.z=9;
pivot.add( torus );
        },
        function (xhr) {
             console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'Texture metalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );
scene.add(pivot);



var torus;
loader.load('img/metalas.jpg',
    function (texture){
        var torusGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 3, 1.2, 6, 100, 6.3 );
        var torusMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/metalas.jpg" );
        torusMaterial.bumpMap = bump;
        torusMaterial.bumpScale = 0.6;
        torusMaterial.metalness = 0.1; // non metal 0-1 metal default 0.5
        torusMaterial.roughness = 0.8; // mirror 0-1 diffuse default 0.5
        torus = new THREE.Mesh(torusGeometry, torusMaterial);
        torus.castShadow = true;
        torus.material.map.repeat.set(0.5,0.5);
        torus.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        torus.position.x=2;
        torus.position.y=-2.48;
        torus.position.z=5;
pivot.add( torus );
        },
        function (xhr) {
             console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'Texture metalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );
scene.add(pivot);


var cylinder;
loader.load('img/metalas.jpg',
    function (texture){
        var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 2.2, 2.2, 2, 64, 1 );
        var cylinderMaterial =  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var bump = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "img/metalas.jpg" );
        cylinderMaterial.bumpMap = bump;
        cylinderMaterial.bumpScale = 0.6;
        cylinderMaterial.metalness = 0.1; // non metal 0-1 metal default 0.5
        cylinderMaterial.roughness = 0.8; // mirror 0-1 diffuse default 0.5
        cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeometry, cylinderMaterial);
        cylinder.castShadow = true;
        cylinder.material.map.repeat.set(0.5,0.5);
        //cylinder.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI;
        cylinder.position.x=2;
        cylinder.position.y=-2.48;
        cylinder.position.z=5;
pivot.add( cylinder );
        },
        function (xhr) {
             console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'Texture metalas.jpg cant be loaded!' );
        }
    );
scene.add(pivot);







    // renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    //renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; //THREE.BasicShadowMap | THREE.PCFShadowMap | THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
    // --- 4 ---

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    fpsContainer.appendChild( stats.dom );

    show();

    function show() {
        requestAnimationFrame( show );

        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        camControls.update( delta );
        pivot.rotation.y += 0;
```

What I have now:

WRONG
[image: WRONG]

NEED THIS
[image: NEED THIS]

Thank you

Comment: I think what's happening here is that `pivot` is rotating, but `cylinder` is not centered in `pivot`. Your two options are to move `pivot` to `cylinder` or to move `cylinder` to `pivot`. I'd offer a proper answer, but I don't know threeJS

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. That and is a problem, I don't know how to do that. Sitting with this problem already 4 hours and nothing. Let's discuss. In my code pivot is rotating, this is a fact. But no code lines with pivot center coordinates. Can it be that pivot center is first added object in it?

Comment: to do this in threejs you'd have to offset the vertices. Also see:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1364

Comment: So the problem was, that all objects was rotating around axes (z-x-y). Thanks for your help.

Comment: When dealing with pivot points, this example helped me a lot: http://jafty.com/blog/three-js-rotate-3d-text-by-its-center-point/#comment-732278